# ngx-daterangepicker-material list click event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-daterangepicker

[image]How to detect click on these items in `ngx-daterangepicker-material`

**my html code**

```
   <form action="" id="dates">
          <input  [class.show-calend]="showCalendar"  readonly="readonly"  id="range-picker" type="text" class="form-control inspection_date"
                 name="dateRange" placeholder="Add date"
                 [formControl]="dateRange" style="cursor: pointer"
                 daterangepicker  [options]="rangeOptions" (cancelDaterangepicker)="cancel($event)" (selected)="selectedDate($event)"/>
          </form>
```